# Xcode Storyboard: Constraints don't let me put space between objects in a stack

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, constraints

i'm learning Swift and programming with Xcode right now.
First of all to get a impression of how everything works I'm doing the Apple Tutorial [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html).

I was building the App exactly how it is described in the tutorial but as i do, it isn't possible for me to get the same result.

Following should be the Result:
[Apple's Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do6vT.png)

Following is the Result I get of:
---PICTURE 2 in Comments---

The Problem is the Gap between the Label / TextBox / Button that is not here in my Version. I don't know why it is so. I did everything exactly like in the Tutorial of Apple. I rechecked everything twice but i don't know what the fault is. Can you please help me? How do I get this gap. Even adding more Constraints for the Items inside of the Stack doesn't work. I just get following Result:

---PICTURE 3 IN COMMENTS---

How do i add this gap or what have I done wrong in the Tutorial?

Thx for your Help!

Comment: Picture 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua14R.png
  Picture 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFYCY.png

Comment: If you have additional information, edit your question ant put it there instead of adding a comment.

Comment: I can't put more than 2 Links into my Post cause i don't have the reputation for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify it in Attributes inspector. Take a look at the following photos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're my Hero! I was searching for this so long! Thx!

Comment: @NicolasMierbach please accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can play with stack view properties, there is one property called spacing set that to the desired spacing which you want.